# Find $\alpha$ for a given trace?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose I have: $\mathbf{A=(\alpha B+I)^{-1}}$. What is $\alpha$ such that: $\text{Trace}\mathbf{\{(I-A)(I-A)^T\}=\gamma}$.

Where $\mathbf{B}$ is a known symmetric $N\times N$ matrix, $\mathbf{I}$ is the identity matrix and $\gamma$ is constant. I can find $\alpha$ that gives me an approximate value for $\gamma$ through a search process, however I'm looking for a more systematic way of finding $\alpha$. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say that for a symetric matrix $S$ we define $\lambda_j(S)$ - its eigenvalues.

First, $(I-A)^T=(I-A)$, because $A$ is symetric. Therefore, $tr((I-A)(I-A)^T) = \sum_j \lambda_j^2(I-A)$. Clearly, $\lambda_j(I-A)= 1-\lambda_j(A) = 1-\frac{1}{\alpha \lambda_j(B)+1}$.

So, you want a solution to a problem
$$\sum_j \left(1-\frac{1}{\alpha \lambda_j(B)+1}\right)^2=\gamma.$$

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, that will surely help.